# Storing an ordered List with JPA/Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

On a Device a user can select the languages of preference in which the content is going to be showed. I have used this for a long time, but updated the system that this list is ordered:

```
@Required
@OrderColumn(name="preferenceOrder")
@ManyToMany(fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
public List<Language> languages;
```

But when I try to update the list with the following code:

```
try{
    // Get the codes of the Device
    Device device = Device.findById(deviceId);
    device.languages.clear();
    for(String langCode : languageCodes){
        Language lang = Language.findByCode(langCode);
        device.languages.add(lang);
    }

    device.save();
    return true;
} catch (Exception e) {
    Logger.error(e, "Problem with updating the languages for device: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    return false;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
15:30:36,376 ERROR ~ Problem with updating the languages for device: org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchedTooManyRowsAffectedException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 5; expected: 1
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchedTooManyRowsAffectedException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 5; expected: 1
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1389)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1317)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1323)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:965)
    at play.db.jpa.JPABase._save(JPABase.java:41)
    at play.db.jpa.GenericModel.save(GenericModel.java:215)
    at logic.helpers.LanguageUpdatePerformer.doJobWithResult(LanguageUpdatePerformer.java:47)
    at logic.helpers.LanguageUpdatePerformer.doJobWithResult(LanguageUpdatePerformer.java:1)
    at play.jobs.Job.call(Job.java:146)
    at play.jobs.Job$1.call(Job.java:66)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchedTooManyRowsAffectedException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 5; expected: 1
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.checkBatched(Expectations.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.verifyOutcome(Expectations.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.checkRowCounts(BatchingBatcher.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareBatchStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.insertRows(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1401)
    at org.hibernate.action.CollectionUpdateAction.execute(CollectionUpdateAction.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:187)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:345)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:962)
    ... 12 more
```

What is the reason for this?
I find 5 records, which is right is this case, but expects 1?
Is it because I first clear the whole list, and should I use another way? This is just the easiest for me to add them in the order they are given me.

Comment: Can you get hibernate to show the sql its generating, then we can really see what its doing:
<property name="show_sql">true</property>

Comment: It returns tons of data. I think however that it only seems to try and update one item: Hibernate: update Device_Language set languages_id=? where Device_id=? and preferenceOrder=?

Comment: (I have a test runner doing the same job, and it works fine, so cannot put my finger on it why it doesn't work in the situation above)

Comment: Oooh, I know the problem. I added this sorted field, and they are all set to 0. So the update does return 5 instead of 1 I think.